# SIGINT singal is being catched only once

Tags: c, unix, signals, sigint

Here's a simple recreation of this issue:

```
void handler(int sig){
        if(sig == SIGINT){
                printf("Signal caught\n");
                execl("./recreate","./recreate",NULL);
        }
}

int main(){
    printf("Main start\n");
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
    while(1);

        return 0;
}
```

It simply runs itself again after receiving the signal. What happens is that it is only able to read CTR+C from the terminal once. From the second point onward is simply writes ^C on the console. Do I need to reset the handler every time or something similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behavior of `signal` depends on the Unix variant you have. To get consistent behavior use [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) instead.

Comment: There is good documentation for signal handling in general and the `signal()` function in particular available online and via the `man` command.

Comment: Also note that `printf` is not considered to be a safe function to call in a signal handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signal` is highly implementation defined and you should use `sigaction` because of that. What you're observing are the so-called sysv semantics of `signal`--the signal is reset in the handler to `SIG_DFL` and it's not blocked from reexecution.

You probably want something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WRITE_LIT(fd, lit) write(fd, lit, sizeof lit - 1)

void handler(int sig){
        if(sig == SIGINT){
            WRITE_LIT(2, "Signal caught\n");
            execl("./recreate","./recreate", (char*)NULL);
            WRITE_LIT(2, "Couldn't run ./recreate\n");
            _exit(127);
        }
}

int main(){
    printf("Main start\n");
    sigaction(SIGINT, &(struct sigaction const){ 
        .sa_handler = handler, 
        .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER /*don't block signals for the new process image*/
    },
    0);
    while(1);
        return 0;
}
```

This won't reset the signal and it won't block it either (the default is to block it for the duration of the handler) because the new process image likely won't want it blocked.